# What's the meaning of "be usually reserved for" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> As a very general proposition, capital crimes are usually reserved for
>   murder

quoted from CNN student news

I looked up the phrase 'reserve' in the Merriam Webster dictionary.

> : to make arrangements so that you will be able to use or have
>   (something, such as a room, table, or seat) at a later time
>
> : to keep (something) for a special or future use
>
> : to choose to do (something) at a later time

The definition I found doesn't correspond or match well in the sentence I quoted.

I guess the sentence's meaning is that generally we think murder as a main or representative type of capital crimes.

Could you help me understand the meaning of the phrase "be reserved for" in this sentence?

Comment: Are you sure it says "crimes"? It sounds like a weird sentence to me.

Comment: Never mind, I [found it](http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1503/05/sn.01.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's sloppy speech. With more time to think, or in writing, the speaker probably would have said:

> Capital **punishment** is usually reserved for murder.

The mistaken wording probably arose because the speaker was trying to refer to the way that capital crimes are defined, but it's hard to think of a way to say this without clumsy grammar. By the time he's said "capital crimes" as the subject of the sentence, he's in trouble:

> "Capital **crimes** are usually" (thinking…) defined so that…only murder can be a capital crime. (Oh, no, that would sound stupid. What's another way to say this?) The definitions of capital crimes are usually very strict: that category is normally reserved for serious crimes like murder. (But I already said "Capital crimes are usually". How do I get out of this? Uh…) "reserved for murder…and not just murder" (I need something stronger, to illustrate my point that we don't define just any small crime as a capital crime) "but murder plus some additional facts that make it particularly egregious." (There, that was technically wrong but I blabbered enough dignified-sounding words after my mistake that people probably won't notice.)

The relevant sense of **reserved** is the second one you listed, which is a metaphorical extension of the first sense. The idea is that capital punishment is the "[last resort](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/last_resort)" in criminal penalties. Metaphorically, we have many criminal penalties, varying in severity from community service to paying a fine to a short prison sentence to a long prison sentence to death. We "[save](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/save#Verb)" death as a punishment for only the worst crimes, as if the death penalty were like expensive silverware that we use only on special occasions.

Answer (score 4):

I read the [transcript](http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1503/05/sn.01.html) it comes from, and the most fitting is definition #2: **to keep something for a special use**

The death penalty is reserved for murder i.e., it is an option ONLY in case of murder *and not just murder, but murder plus some additional facts that make it particularly egregious* [cit.]

Now, the use of "crime" seems a bit awkward to me. The closest I can get to is [Capital Offense](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/capital-offense), but it makes way more sense with "Punishment". CNN probably knows English better than I do, so I'll wait for some native to drop in and explain that part to me.

Comment: +1 I'd choose "are (only) kept for" as the explanation, too. Note that **[capital crime](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/capital-crime)** has a specific meaning: "crime for which the punishment is death"